# CakePHP passing data to component before instantiation

Tags: cakephp

I have a component that uses some classes to do the job it's supposed to do. I need to pass data to it so it instantiates objects that it's going to need. How can I do it?

Should I use `initialize(&$Controller, $settings = array())` callback? If so, how can I populate `$settings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Component::initialize` is usually a good place to do this and the `$settings` variable can be populated through your `Controller::$components` array:

```
public $components = array('Foobar' => array('baz' => 42));
// array('baz' => 42) will be passed as the second argument ($settings) to
// FoobarComponent::initialize(&$Controller, $settings)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the other problem that I'm facing is that the value that I need to pass, 42 in this case, is actually a value that I need to retrieve from database. So if I use the variable, I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`.

Comment: @Jon Yeah, that won't work. You'll have to do that in a controller method like `beforeFilter`, at which point the component is already up and running. So you'll have to structure the component to do its job at some later point and pass it the necessary information after it has been initialized. You can simply do `$this->Foobar->baz = 42` at any point in the controller, or create a setter method in your component you'll call from the controller. Look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/996/Creating-Components for all the possible callback points a component has.

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping to do it the other way, but seems like there's no other choice.